# nslookup returning local router name and address

Tags: nslookup

I am using `nslookup` to query external servers such as google.com, but when I do this what I am getting back is my router's name and IP address.

Nslookup response after hitting google.com

```
  $ nslookup
    Default Server:  home.router
    Address:  <my router's IP>

    > set querytype=ns
    > google.com
    Non-authoritative answer:
    Server:  home.router
    Address:  <my router's IP>

    google.com      nameserver = ns4.google.com
    google.com      nameserver = ns1.google.com
    google.com      nameserver = ns2.google.com
    google.com      nameserver = ns3.google.com

    ns1.google.com  internet address = 216.239.32.10
    ns2.google.com  internet address = 216.239.34.10
    ns3.google.com  internet address = 216.239.36.10
    ns4.google.com  internet address = 216.239.38.10
```

Any idea why it keeps returning my local router name and address instead of a google DNS server? What can I do to circumvent this behaviour?

Please note that I receive the same result for many other nslookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is typically the result when your router is acting as a captive portal and functioning by [redirecting DNS responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal#Redirect_by_DNS).

Comment: This is incorrect. Check joeqwerty's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are telling you which server is handling your query. Those lines are not the answer to your query. Where's the rest of the output from nslookup?

```
C:\Users\joe>nslookup
Default Server:  MyDnsServer.example.com
Address:  192.0.2.1

> set querytype=ns
> google.com
Server:  MyDnsServer.example.com
Address:  192.0.2.1

Non-authoritative answer:
google.com      nameserver = ns2.google.com
google.com      nameserver = ns4.google.com
google.com      nameserver = ns1.google.com
google.com      nameserver = ns3.google.com

ns2.google.com  internet address = 216.239.34.10
ns4.google.com  internet address = 216.239.38.10
ns1.google.com  internet address = 216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com  internet address = 216.239.36.10
>
```

Comment: I am getting the same response as you have shown here, apart from our `Server` and `Address` values being different (mine still shows my router details)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're saying. How about posting the entire output of nslookup in your question so that we can see what it is that you're talking about.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the full response.

Comment: @ethane Please mark this as the accepted answer. The other is incorrect.